# Does my stray kitten have neuro issues?

Tags: cats

I have brought in a female kitten from a busy railway area into my apartment building compound but I don't keep her at home, since it's too small. I and my friend feed her wet kitten food and is well taken care of most of the time. We have noticed she meows silently most of the time, is disinterested in playing with anything (balls, strings etc). She eats fine but is skinny and walks weirdly, it looks like she lacks strength. She sits on my lap and likes to sleep and knead me but bites a lot when you stretch out our hand to her, especially fingers. Rarely licks but definitely bites a lot. 
Also she keeps rubbing her head against a lot of things and even with people she isn't familiar. 
Her pupil of one eye is normal but the other is misshapen and probably doesn't constrict in bright light. 
Overall she is not interested in anything and her behaviour does signal towards some neurological issues. She is a few weeks old, not sure though since I found her on the street. She is a really young kitty and most her age are often quite agile and playful but she seems to be having a very different behaviour in almost every aspect. I am very confused. Please help.

Comment: Take it to the vet immediately. A couple things of note, however, if by "rubbing her head against a lot of things" it's more like she's pressing her head on things, that is a symptom of a neurological problem. https://purrfectlove.net/cat-head-pressing/ The mention of the misshapen pupil makes me question whether the kitten can actually see also. Again, you should really take it to a vet ASAP.

Comment: I have already scheduled an appointment. Thanks a lot for the input. I have also seen her lift her front paws alternatively while sitting down on her hind legs. Does that mean something too?

Comment: I don't know if that means anything or not.